# Delete a image file from folder in opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I need to delete the image file in the cache folder.

use unlink for delete image file,

```
if (file_exists(DIR_IMAGE . $image_new)) {
    unlink(DIR_IMAGE . $image_new);
}
```

but, it returns the error,

> Warning:
>   unlink(../image/upload/image/cache/catalog/sample_img-47x47.jpg):
>   Permission denied

How can I delete the images?

I'm looking forward to a solution.

Comment: `Permission denied` Check permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your image absolute path is correct and you have folder permission "0755".